# Zip-deploy Azure functions while public access is disabled (access restrictions are in place)

Tags: azure, visual-studio, github-actions

I disabled `Allow public access` on an Azure Function App for security reasons:

[image]
However after that, zip deploys from Visual Studio (publish functionality) and via Github Actions fail, as the API for deployment isn't publicly reachable anymore. In that case, how would one zip deploy updated Azure functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need ZIP deployment, you need to deploy the code from inside the VNET to the private endpoint of the AppService. For GitHub Actions, this means deploying a [self-hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) on a VM inside the VNET to **push the new code** to AppService. There is an [example for Azure DevOps self-hosted agents.](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/01/04/deploying-to-network-secured-sites.html)

As an alternative, you can publish your ZIP to a storage account and let the function **pull the new application code** to run. There is also a [full example including GitHub Actions](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/01/deploying-to-network-secured-sites-2.html).

The most relevant quotes from the second example are:

> This article shows how to deploy to a Private Endpoint-enabled site from a Continuous Integration pipeline (such as GitHub Actions, Circle CI, Jenkins, or Travis CI) without having to self-host the CI service on a VM. Since Private Endpoints disables all **inbound** traffic from the internet, our CI pipeline will publish the files to a storage account and give the web app a SAS URL to files. Once the web app is given this SAS URL, it will pull the files from the storage account.

```yaml
      - name: Set SAS token expiration
        run: echo "expiry=`date -u -d "$EXPIRY_TIME" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ'`" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Azure CLI script
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          azcliversion: 2.19.1
          inlineScript: |
            az extension add --name webapp

            az storage account create   -n $ACCOUNT   -g $GROUP -l westus
            az storage container create -n $CONTAINER --account-name $ACCOUNT
            az storage blob upload      -f app.zip    --account-name $ACCOUNT -c $CONTAINER -n $ACCOUNT

            ZIP_URL=$(az storage blob generate-sas --full-uri --permissions r --expiry ${{ env.expiry }} --account-name $ACCOUNT -c $CONTAINER -n $ACCOUNT | xargs)

            az webapp deploy --name $WEBAPP --resource-group $GROUP --type zip --src-url  $ZIP_URL --async false

            az storage container delete -n $CONTAINER --account-name $ACCOUNT
```

Comment: thanks for all the details :-) bounty awarded :-)